# Using for loop in a for loop to generate rows with content

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, for-loop, asp.net-core

I'm trying to generate a View like the following

[image: What I'm trying to achieve]

The count of the rows is predetermined in my server side code. I'm currently struggling to access the data of my items in my list.

```
<div class = "row">
 <div class = "col-12" >
 @for(int i = 1; i <= Model.RowCount; i++) {
  <div class = "row" >
   @for(int j = 0; j < Model.List.Count; j++) {
    <div class = "col-3 p-3 mb-4 ml-4 bg-dark text-white rounded">
     <b > @Model.List[j].Value < /b> 
     </div>
   } 
   </div>
 } 
  </div>
</div>
```

What I'm exactly trying to do is divide my list into three parts and generate three items per row. After one row has been filled with content, it should move on to the next row and continue to generate content, without losing track of the last item it has accessed.

For example: The server generated the last item of row 1 and moves on to row 2. This means that the last item of row 1 was list[2]. Now the first item in the next row should be list[3].

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You have to be more specific. What kind of error are you getting? What kind of output are you getting? As it stands you are subject to downvotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class = "row">
 <div class = "col-12" >
 @var index = 0;
 @for(int i = 1; i <= Model.RowCount; i++) {
  <div class = "row" >
   @for(int j = 0; j < Model.List.Count; j++) {
    index++;
    <div class = "col-3 p-3 mb-4 ml-4 bg-dark text-white rounded">
     <b > @Model.List[index].Value < /b> 
     </div>
   } 
   </div>
 } 
  </div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class = "row">
 <div class = "col-12" >
 @for(int i = 1; i <= Model.RowCount; i++) {
  <div class = "row" >
   @for(int j = 0; j < Model.List.Count; j++) {
    var index = Model.List.Count * (i-1) + j;
    <div class = "col-3 p-3 mb-4 ml-4 bg-dark text-white rounded">
     <b > @Model.List[index].Value < /b> 
     </div>
   } 
   </div>
 } 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you so much!